# Is there a special name/word or popular phrase for the students who work part-time/full-time to generate income?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, speech

Is there a special name/word or popular phrase for the students who work part-time/full-time to generate income while at college or in school?

Comment: As a professor in a second-tier public university in the U.S., I just call them *students.* Those with sufficient family (or trust-fund) financial support to attend without simultaneously holding down paid jobs are a small minority; one might almost better seek a distinguishing term for *them,* perhaps *scholars of means.* Of course, elsewhere in the world it can be a very different story.

Comment: For undergraduates who are employed by the school itself (assisting teachers, working in the library, etc.), the term has always been "work-study" students, in my experience. For graduate students employed assisting professors in their academic fields, the term is "research assistant", or "RA", or if with their teaching tasks (e.g. grading), "teaching assistant", or "TA", again in my experience.

Comment: @tchrist Are you sure there is a reasonable answer there? (Not that I can think of one.)

Comment: @BrianDonovan, what about "Students with jobs".

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the term *non-traditional*. Though this phrase can also include older, returning or other categories of students who do not conform to the tradition of entering right after high school, living on campus and studying full-time.